# Проблема с кодом на сайте

Tags: php

Добрый день! Помогите разобраться с ошибкой на сайте

> header.php on line 248

После манипуляций с кодом сайт стал недоступен и стал выдавать такую ошибку. Подскажите, куда смотреть?

```
</table>                    
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" background="/bitrix/templates/digisnew/images/tbl_news_right.jpg" width="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">
        <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td>
        <?
        }               
        ?>      
<?if ($IS_MAIN_PAGE != "true") {?>              
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td></td><?}?>#WORK_AREA#     <?if ($IS_MAIN_PAGE != "true") {?>    <tr>
        <td height="5"><img border="0" sr
```

Вот фрагмент кода. Очевидно, ошибка в самом конце, тк PHP файл так заканчиваться не может!

Comment: Все просто - на линию 248 файла header.php

Comment: А вообще неплохо было написать часть кода, где возможна ошибка и тип ошибки, который указан в error message. Тогда есть шанс подсказать верное решение.

Comment: И что из этого - строка 248?  
Если это самый-самый конец файла, то дела ваши плохи: вы обрезали файл и теперь вам придется его восстанавливать.

Comment: Какой тип ошибки?

Comment: error message
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end "адрес файла"/header.php on line 248

Comment: Не хватает, скорее всего, закрывающейся скобки `}` этой конструкции 

    <?if ($IS_MAIN_PAGE != "true") {?>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?if ($IS_MAIN_PAGE != "true") {?>
```

Код не закрыт, не хватает `<?}?>`

И покажите полный код ошибки, тут не экстрасенсы.

`unexpected $end` означает, что не закрыта скобка после условия. Закройте её как я описал выше.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще то информации очень мало, но я позволю себе одеть телепатический шлем и попробывать ответить.

---

Боюсь что сайт редактируется непосредственно из самого же сайта. В следствии чего открыть админку (что то мне подсказывает что это WordPress) и вернуть всё как было не предоставляется возможным.

Если всё это так - то тут есть единственный выход: Наверняка доступ к сайту есть по ftp или ssh. Поэтому нужно зайти на сайт и поправить этот файл.